# ActiveRecord join with select Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following AR relations,

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :deals
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

What I want to do is to find the deals with given tags, and return the related `restaurants`.

I have the following scope in my `Restaurant` model

```
scope :food_type, ->(food_types){
  select("*")
  joins(:deals).merge(Deal.tagged_with([food_types], any: true, wild: true )) 
}
```

But the issue is, when I call `Restaurant.food_type(<tags>)` it returns ActiveRecord relation with `Restaurant` objects with `Deal` data

Ex: `#<Restaurant id: 383, name: "sample deal name", note: "sample deal note", created_at: "2014-03-18 22:36:27", updated_at: "2014-03-18 22:36:27"`

I even used `select` in the scope , without any luck. How can I return `Restaurant` attributes from the above scope?

Comment: how did you use select? ``select('restaurants.*')`` ?

Comment: @mkk, thanks for the answer, but it didnt work ;(